# The concept of linking objects and classes

Tags: object-oriented

This isn't so much as a specific code review, but a concept review when converting a class diagram to code and then eventually a database, in Python. I know how to add things in to a database, but I have only ever done this directly with SQL from forms and not from classes, (which I believe is called ORM)

I have the following class diagram

[image]

I have created the following classes to match the diagram

```
class Member:

  def __init__(self):
    self.memid = 0
    self.memname = ""

  def addMember(self, memid, memname):
    self.memid = memid
    self.memname = memname

  def searchbyid(memid):
    return 0

  def searchbyname(memname):
    return 0

  def newcust(self, custid, custname):  
    self.custid = custid
    self.custname = custname

class Rental:

  def __init__(self):
    self.title = ""
    self.sartdate = ""
    self.enddate = ""
    self.cost = 0

  def addrental(self, title, startdate, enddate, cost):
    self.title = title
    self.startdate = startdate
    self.enddate = enddate
    self.cost = 0

class Movie:

  def __init__(self):
    self.movieID = 0
    self.title = ""
    self.genre = ""
    self.runtime = 0.0

  def newMovie(self, movieID, title, genre, runtime):
    self.movieID = movieID
    self.title = title
    self.genre = genre
    self.runtime = runtime
```

Forgetting the specific syntax (for example, data types, best practice etc) My question is, how do I get these to work together to model the real world scenario I have? I know I can create a member like this:

```
member = Member()
member.addMember(1, "John Sampson")
```

And I know I can create a movie like this:

```
movie = Movie()
movie.newMovie(47, "Die Hard", "Action", 94.27)
```

But when joining these things together to create a rental, would I do it like this?:

```
member.rental = Rental()
member.rental.addrental(movie.title, "07/02/2018", "18/02/2018", 10)
```

My further questions are:

How do I specifically link together classes as I have in my diagram (1 member having many rentals etc.) or would the link only be created when the data is passed in to a database?

How would I create a member search function? Would this only be able to work once I had a database up and running?

In my example above, I add Die Hard as the movie they rented because it's the only one I have an object for. However in the real world, they could choose any movie, so I assume I would have to search for the movie they entered and then link it from there. However, how would I search for a movie when objects have been created and before they have been added to the database? Would I add each object to a list as they are added?

I'm getting very stuck conceptually between the action of creating simple classes, and the method of making them work together so that we know a member has rented this specific video and we know the rental was for this movie etc.

Comment: If you want an ORM, why don't you just use an existing ORM, instead of trying to invent your own? Or at least just read about a few, to see how they do these things. All of your problems have already been solved by existing ORMs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have an id for rentals. A member might rent the same movie again and thus the pair (movieID, memberID) does not identify a rental.

I think you should treat Rental as an independent aggregate root. In practice this means you don't have direct object references between Movies, Members and Rentals. Instead a Rental knows the ID of the movie and the ID of the member involved.

Movies and Members don't need any references to Rentals. You should be able to write the functionality of registering and browsing movies and members without even thinking about Rentals yet.

If your system is about renting physical copies of movies, then members aren't exactly renting movies but copies. There's a 1:N relationship between Movies and Copies.

Also, about the ´float cost´: use decimals instead of binary floating numbers for money. You need precise decimal values there.

> How would I create a member search function? Would this only be able to work once I had a database up and running?

You could always write a MemberRepository that works in memory instead of connecting to a database.

> In my example above, I add Die Hard as the movie they rented because it's the only one I have an object for. However in the real world, they could choose any movie, so I assume I would have to search for the movie they entered and then link it from there.

In the real world the user (a Member) sees a list of Movies. The system knows the IDs of those Movies. The system also knows the ID of the Member. When the user chooses to rent a Movie, the backend gets the ID of the Movie and the ID of the Member as parameters. There's no need to search the Movie by name or anything.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The floating points are just there are holders. I'm not intending to do anything with this, I'm just using it to wrap my head around the concepts.

Is the method I used to assign a rental to a customer appropriate? Is that how I should combine classes in to a single object?

Comment: @user1480135 It seems to me that you're struggling with classes and objects. For instance, you having a method like addMember as an instance method of Member does not make a lot of sense. Adding a Member should be an operation of a backend service. Alternatively, for a very small scale practice, you could have such method as a class method of Member.

Comment: thanks. The class diagram is just copied from an OOP book. I just wanted something as an example to illustrate the difficulties I was having.

Comment: @user1480135 Ok, I see. A problem with many introductory level books about OOP and OO languages is that the examples deal with only classes that are related to real life objects: Movie, Member, Rental etc. In real life applications there are also classes that relate to functions and design of the system itself. There could be a MovieService and a MovieRepository class in an application like this. Perhaps you should look for examples of Python applications and/or books that cover not only OOP but also software architecture and design.